# Proper approach for grading a quiz

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have an application that presents 3 different quizzes one at a time over a 3 week period. It is being used as an internal employee contest aimed at giving knowledge about one of the client's products. I have coded the front end using .NET aspx pages and it displays the quiz. I then have a class file that is being used to grade the quiz. What I am stuck on is the correct approach to store the answers in the class. Obviously the answers will be static and not change. There are 5 questions per quiz.

One approach I thought of was to declare some variables in the class that grades the quiz, one per answer per quiz and then pass in the quiz that has been taken and use the contents of those variables to grade the quiz. That is not very object-oriented. So, without over complicating things, would it be better to create a class for each quiz that has the answers and then I can create an instance of that class and just read in Class.Answer1, etc? A rough example would be:

```
public class QuizOne {
   public property answer1 = "A";
   public property answer2 = "B";
   public property answer3 = "B";
   public property answer4 = "C";
   public property answer5 = "E";
}
```

I could have one class like this per quiz. Then I could have some code in the grading class that looks up which class to instantiate and then once instantiated I could do:

```
if(quiz.answer1 == answered1){
// do something for the correct answer 
} else {
// do something for the incorrect answer
}
```

Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Maybe take this to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @puddinman13 There is no code to review. This is more or less a [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) problem.

Comment: @EBrown I'm not sure that this is a good Programmers question either.

Comment: @200_success: ["Ask about...Software architecture and design"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @200_success According to the [Programmers Help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `If you have a question about...`, `software requirements`, `software architecture and design`, and `algorithm and data structure concepts` **all** fit in for this question. (The content may not be *the best*, but it's far from *not good*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a broad question, so this answer is a bit broad, but it sounds like you could go for some right-proper object-design here.

First, I would declare `Quiz` in general (in the C#) as a class. Something along the following:

```
public class Quiz
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I would declare a `Question` class:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, declare an `Answer` class:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

It should be pretty clear where to go from here. The correct answer would be indicated with `Points > 0`, and incorrect answers would have `Points = 0`.

Then, you can extend this in the future for other things.

You can save it to the database in many ways. The easiest is a two-column `Quiz` table, one column for the `Id (uniqueidentifier)`, the other for `Questions (nvarchar(max))`. You can use the built-in [`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or the [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to get it to the database.

You then award `Points` based on correctness. (I use this for projects on occasion, as some of my `Quizes` and `Tests` have multiple *correct* answers, with some being more correct than others. This means that if the answer B and C are both *technically* correct, and answer D is `B and C`, then answer D would be awarded more points, and so on.) You also don't need to worry about `A/B/C/D/E` here, as **technically** that is a **display-problem**.

Also, note: this is a **very basic** representation of how I usually tackle the problem, but it should definitely get you started.

---

Also, this is more fitting on the StackExchange site [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

[Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> If you have a question about...
>
> - software requirements
> - software architecture and design
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
>
> ...
>
> ...then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 1):

EBrown has a quality answer and certainly more correct and will support weighted question values.  If you are in a large company and are providing company wide training that is a better solution.  It doesn't really sound like that's what is happening to me (and I could be mistaken) so I thought I'd throw out another option that's quick and dirty:

```
class Question{
    public string QuestionText {get; set;}
    public ICollection<string> AnswerChoices {get; set;}
    public string CorrectAnswer {get; set;}
    public string AnswerProvided {get;set;}
}

public decimal GradeQuiz(ICollection<Question> questions){

    if(questions.Count == 0){
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot grade a quiz with no questions");
    }

    var correct = questions.Count(x => x.AnswerProvided == x.CorrectAnswer);
    var total = questions.Count;
    return (decimal)correct * 100 / total;
}
```

Comment: This is a very quick/easy/dirty method as you said, and does in fact successfully fill the OP's requirements with little work. It is a very good alternative to my post. Though, you did spell `grade` as `grad`. :P Unfortunately, my answer is built for such a wide-case set of scenarios as I do all of this for the corporate environment, and they have very strict requirements.

Comment: Yep.  Yours is a more flexible and a better design.  But when there are comments like "storing the answer in the class file" it makes me think that level of design isn't required for this problem.  Thanks for catching the spelling mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the question, the possible answers, and the correct answer inside a `QuestionAndAnswers` class. Something like:

```
public class QuestionAndAnswers
{
   private readonly Dictionary<int, string> _answers;

   public string Question { get; set; }

   public Dictionary<int, string> Answers { get { return _answers; } }

   public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

   // Perhaps add a grade/points enumeration and a property to use it here,
   // if some questions are worth more than others

   public QuestionAndAnswers()
   {
      // You would probably want to provide arguments to the constructor
      // and make the class immutable
      _answers = new Dictionary<int, string> ();
   }
}
```

...where `Answers` is a dictionary containing the 'possible answer' strings and the identifying number (id) of each. You could go further and have a list of `Answer` objects but I'm not sure that's necessary as each answer is no more than a string.

I would then have a `Quiz` class which would expose a `Dictionary<int, QuestionAndAnswers>` (or `IDictionary`) where the `int` is the question number. I prefer this to having a number property in the `QuestionAndAnswers` class as the number is really a feature of the quiz and not the question.